# ZURB Foundation Topbar Bug, Onclick highlights other link Mobile

Tags: css, html, zurb-foundation

Im using the ZURB Foundation Topbar, I like it apart from a bug I've found. On 2nd level drop downs, if you highlight then click on the link (li elements) just before it takes you to the page you clicked on, the active highlight flicks to one of the above elements and back.

---[The reason its flicking to one of the above elements, is due to it being the 1st level dropdown to be selected, for some reason it flicks to the previous level drop down then back the the 2nd level choice]---Still No idea to fix it though.

[image]

```
   <!-- Nav Section Mobile-->
   <div class="top-bar-container hide-for-large-up">
   <nav class="top-bar">
   <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name"></li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
   </ul>
<section class="top-bar-section"> 
<!-- Nav Section -->
 <ul class="">
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    <li class=""><a title="" href="/page.html">page</a></li>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    <li class=""><a title="" href="/page.html">page</a></li>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    <li class=""><a title="" href="/page.html">page</a></li>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>

    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">pages</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html" >page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html" >page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">More</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
        <li><a href="/page.html">page</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="divider hide-for-small"></li>
  </ul>
</section>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Foundation 4 there is a bug because of a pseudo class being used with a colon `:`. It should be a period `.` after the `li`:

```css
.top-bar-section ul li:hover > a {
```

It should read:

```css
.top-bar-section ul li.hover > a {
```

That'll fix it right up